# Presentation View in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, display, presentation

I have a very specific question.

I want to implement a "Presentation Mode". Example: I connect my iPad in classroom to an external display. In the App, I have a part of the screen, where I can draw. The other half displays e.g the weather.
Here's the thing: I just want to display the drawing to the external display.

I do not want to mirror my whole iPad Screen to the external display.
I know there is a package called "presentation_displays" but it handles the external display just as new screen, but I want to mirror a part of the iPad Screen.

Do you have an idea how to implement it? Is it even possible in Flutter?
Thank you!